# HTML localStorage Returns Null

Tags: javascript, html, function, local-storage

My localStorage returns null, and I don't know why, the read function is not used, but just for help I put it anyway. Chrome says that it cannot ste innerHTML into null, and my troubleshooting alert info also returns null, but the code goes to the end. Any help would be useful, thank you. 
The cookie:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <cookie>
      <script>localStorage.setItem('id',Math.floor(Math.random()*10))
</script>
    </cookie>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>var id = localStorage.getItem('id')
    alert(id)</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The Script:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>

    <script>
    var theId=localStorage.getItem('id')


    function change(id,target){
      var info = localStorage.getItem(id);
      alert(info)
      document.getElementById(target).innerHTML=info;
    }
    function read(){
      var element=document.createElement('h1')
      element.innerHTML='You Want To Read'
      document.body.appendChild(element)
      alert('debug')

    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Read" name="read_story" id="read_story" 
onclick=read();change(theId,info)>
    <p id='info'>initial</p>
  </body>
  <script>
  alert('debug');

  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried just setting a hard coded value and seeing if getItem after that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misinterpreted the error message.

If it can't set the `innerHTML` of `null` then you have `something.innerHTML = a_value`. It is the `something` that is `null` not anything to do with local storage.

In `change(theId,info)`, `info` is a variable. It is a reference to the element with `id="info"`.

You use it here: `document.getElementById(target)`.

`info` (now `target`) gets converted into a string (`"[object HTMLParagraphElement]"`).

There is no element with `id="[object HTMLParagraphElement]"`, so you get `null`.

When you call the function, you need to pass a **string**, not a variable.

Comment: Thank you, but how do I pass the variable as a string to let the function return localStorage.getItem('id') into innerHTML?

Comment: @JohnHao — You put quotes around it.